# How can I summarize / pivot data with oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table containing geological resource information.

```
| Property | Zone | Area        | Category  | Tonnage | Au_gt | Au_oz |
|----------|------|-------------|-----------|---------|-------|-------|
| Ket      | Eel  | Open Pit    | Measured  | 43400   | 5.52  | 7700  |
| Ket      | Eel  | Open Pit    | Inferred  | 51400   | 5.88  | 9700  |
| Ket      | Eel  | Open Pit    | Indicated | 357300  | 6.41  | 73600 |
| Ket      | Eel  | Underground | Measured  | 3300    | 7.16  | 800   |
| Ket      | Eel  | Underground | Inferred  | 14700   | 6.16  | 2900  |
| Ket      | Eel  | Underground | Indicated | 168100  | 8.85  | 47800 |
```

I would like to summarize the data so that it can be read more easily by our clients.

```
| Property | Zone | Category  | Open_Pit_Tonnage | Open_Pit_Au_gt | Open_Pit_Au_oz | Underground_tonnage | Underground_au_gt | Underground_au_oz | Combined_tonnage | Combined_au_gt | Combined_au_oz |
|----------|------|-----------|------------------|----------------|----------------|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|------------------|----------------|----------------|
| Ket      | Eel  | Measured  | 43,400           | 5.52           | 7,700          | 3,300               | 7.16              | 800               | 46,700           | 5.64           | 8,500          |
| Ket      | Eel  | Indicated | 357,300          | 6.41           | 73,600         | 168,100             | 8.85              | 47,800            | 525,400          | 7.19           | 121,400        |
| Ket      | Eel  | Inferred  | 51,400           | 5.88           | 9,700          | 14,700              | 6.16              | 2,900             | 66,100           | 5.94           | 12,600         |
```

I'm fairly new to pivot tables.  How could I write a query to translate and summarize the data?

Thanks!

Comment: The numbers you show in the last column (`combined_au_oz`) seem wrong - for example in the first row the individual numbers are `7,700` and `800`, how do you get the sum of `54,400`?

Comment: @mathguy - good catch. ill update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Oracle version is 11.1 or higher (which it should be if you are a relatively new user!) then you can use the `PIVOT` operator, as shown below.

Note that the result of the `PIVOT` operation can be given an alias (I used `p`) - this makes it easier to write the `SELECT` clause.

I assumed the name of your table is `geological_data` - replace it with your actual table name.

```
select p.*
     , open_pit_tonnage + underground_tonnage as combined_tonnage
     , open_pit_au_gt   + underground_au_gt   as combined_au_gt
     , open_pit_au_oz   + underground_au_oz   as combined_au_oz
from   geological_data
pivot  (sum(tonnage) as tonnage, sum(au_gt) as au_gt, sum(au_oz) as au_oz
        for area in ('Open Pit' as open_pit, 'Underground' as underground)) p
;
```

Comment: This works great, thank you so much.  I'm not sure why it works, but i'll play around and see if i can use it to understand pivot tables better.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional aggregation is a simple method:

```
select Property, Zone, Category,
       max(case when area = 'Open Pit' then tonnage end) as open_pit_tonnage,
       max(case when area = 'Open Pit' then Au_gt end) as open_pit_Au_gt,
       max(case when area = 'Open Pit' then Au_oz end) as open_pit_Au_ox,
       max(case when area = 'Underground' then tonnage end) as Underground_tonnage,
       max(case when area = 'Underground' then Au_gt end) as Underground_Au_gt,
       max(case when area = 'Underground' then Au_oz end) as Underground_Au_ox
from t
group by Property, Zone, Category
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server PIVOT operator is used to convert rows to columns.

Goal is to turn the category names from the first column of the output into multiple columns and count the number of products for each category

[image]

This query reference can be taken into account for you above table:

```
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        category_name, 
        product_id,
        model_year
    FROM 
        production.products p
        INNER JOIN production.categories c 
            ON c.category_id = p.category_id
) t 
PIVOT(
    COUNT(product_id) 
    FOR category_name IN (
        [Children Bicycles], 
        [Comfort Bicycles], 
        [Cruisers Bicycles], 
        [Cyclocross Bicycles], 
        [Electric Bikes], 
        [Mountain Bikes], 
        [Road Bikes])
) AS pivot_table;
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between "Oracle SQL" and "SQL Server"? The OP marked the question clearly as "Oracle", so an "SQL Server" answer will get an automatic downvote from me. Feel free to delete your answer, unless you can rewrite it for Oracle. Also please use formatting tools for your code.